# How to change where models and builds are saved by BentoML?

Tags: bentoml

By default, builds are stored at the `~/bentoml/bentos` directory. Can I change it? There's no command line option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an environment variable `BENTOML_HOME` that can be used to change where BentoML save models and builds.